# Advantages of guarded foreign keys on eloquent models

Tags: php, laravel, security, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table called users. This table has a foreign key called project_id in another table called projects. Users on my page will see a dropdown that contains all projects and will be able to select one of them. I will then use the primary key of the selected project to be a foreign key to the newly created user.

Now in laravel's eloquent model, I have read that foreign keys should always be guarded (can't be mass assignable) for security. I don't really understand why that is. Suppose I validated that the project_id exists in the projects table, shouldn't I be confident that the value is valid and can now be mass assigned to the User model? Is there any other reason I'm missing why people say foreign keys should always be guarded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign keys should be guarded as a best practice, but if you are absolutely sure you are sanitizing your input there is no reason why you shouldn't unguard `project_id`.

There are other cases where guarding should really be kept - for example, your users table has a `is_paid_member` field that indicates the user has paid real money to unlock certain features on your site. Let's assume you did not guard that field, and the user goes to his profile page, manipulates the form by adding a `<input type="hidden" name="is_paid_member" value="1">` field, and submits the form.

If you are doing a mass update when saving the profile details - something like `$user->update($request->input())` then the user just got himself a paid account for free.